# Creating a custom Callback for Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, callback, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and Otto in my app for web service calls. I want to assign an id for each request made so I made a custom Retrofit callback like this

```
public class RetrofitCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private static int _idCounter = 1;

    public int requestId;
    private Bus eventBus;

    public RetrofitCallback(Bus eventBus){
        this.requestId = _idCounter;
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        _idCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T data, Response response) {
        // problem.. data is not the type I expected. please see below
        RetrofitRequestSuccess<T> message = new RetrofitRequestSuccess<>(requestId, 
           data, response);
        eventBus.post(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        RetrofitRequestFailed message = new RetrofitRequestFailed(requestId, error);
        eventBus.post(message);
    }
}
```

The RetrofitRequestSuccess class

```
public class RetrofitRequestSuccess<T> {
    public T data;
    public int requestId;
    public Response response;

    public RetrofitRequestSuccess(int requestId, T data, Response response) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.data = data;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

I then use the callback as follows

```
int requestId = 0; // activity level scope

RestAdapter restApiAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ENDPOINT).build();
RestAPI restClient = restApiAdapter.create(RestAPI.class);
RetrofitCallback<List<Order>> callback = new RetrofitCallback<>(BusProvider.getBus());
restClient.getOrders(callback);
requestId = callback.requestId;
```

Otto subscribed method

```
@Subscribe
public void onHttpResponseReceived(RetrofitRequestSuccess message) {
    if(message.requestId == requestId) {
        List<Order> ordersList = (ArrayList<Order>) message.data;
    }
}
```

The problem is I never get List of `Order` objects in `message.data`. No matter what type I pass when I create the callback, the `message.data` always contains a List of Gson's `LinkedTreeMap` objects. How can I make it to return the correct type? Any help would be greatly appreciated!